# SFINAE based on type name

Tags: c++, sfinae

In my search, I've found ways to chose template expansions based on existence of member functions, if a type is integral etc. but what I am trying to do is to have something like SFINAE based on type name. Look at the example taken from another question:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value> f(T t){
    //integral version
}
```

This let's me have a selection based on if type T is integral or not. What I want to do is, let's say I have couple of classes that I defined; `gl_renderable_t`, `vulkan_renderable_t` etc. I want to have something like;

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!T.has_typename(gl_renderable_t)!::value> f(T t){
    // call gl render functions
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!T.has_typename(vulkan_renderable_t)!::value> f(T t){
    // call vulkan render functions
}
```

I want to use SFINAE based on typename basically. This seems it should be easy or at least possible given all the crazy things people do with SFINAE but I could not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::is_same<T, U>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) for this:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<gl_renderable_t, T>> f(T t);
```

---

Note: `std::is_same` works by having a base template accepting `T, U` and a partial specialisation for `T, T` requiring identical types. The specialisation provides the `true` value and the base has the `false` value:

```
template<class T, class U>
struct is_same : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_same<T, T> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: @tobi303 yes... they're just aliases. Nothing surprising here. For what it's worth, names aren't totally irrelevant: `struct A { int x; };` and `struct B { int x; };` are different types. `using C = A;` introduces a new name `C` which is an alias for type `A`.

Comment: uff sorry, i think i just misread the question and OP wasnt talking about names of types at all but was just refering to `typename T`